# Simple calculator using python gui tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.x

I am trying to make a simple calculator that gives square and square root with using Python 2.7.10 with GUI but it doesn't work I can't figure out what is the problem. I receive this error:

> ```
> > Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File
> > "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in call return
> > self.func(*args) File "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/simplecalc.py", line 5, in
> > do_sqrt root = x**0.5 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or
> > pow(): 'str' and 'float'
> ```

```
import Tkinter    
import tkMessageBox

def do_sqrt():
    root = x**0.5
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Square Root = ", x)

def do_square():
    square = x**2
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Square = ", x)

main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
main_window.title("Simple Calc")
number_input = (Tkinter.Entry(main_window))
x = number_input.get()
button_sqrt = Tkinter.Button(main_window, text = "Square Root", command = do_sqrt)
button_sqrt.pack()
button_square = Tkinter.Button(main_window, text = "Square", command =     do_square)
button_square.pack()
number_input.pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" how exactly? Errors? Incorrect results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add more details to clarify the question you are asking and provide necessary context.

Comment: Window pops and I enter a number to the box then click to square root button or square button but then I get this error.

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/simplecalc.py", line 5, in do_sqrt
    root = x**0.5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'

Comment: @AliBeyit Please [edit] your question to add those details.  They're very hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the string from the entry and trying to perform some math.
And you are not using root and square variables.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox


def do_sqrt():
    root = float(number_input.get())**0.5
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Square Root = ", root)


def do_square():
    square = float(number_input.get())**2
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Square = ", square)

main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
main_window.title("Simple Calc")
number_input = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
button_sqrt = Tkinter.Button(main_window, text="Square Root", command=do_sqrt)
button_sqrt.pack()
button_square = Tkinter.Button(main_window, text="Square", command=do_square)
button_square.pack()
number_input.pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh thanks god. I thought I tried this but forgot to write float around the number_input.get(). Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: you are welcome. I would also suggest to stick with OOP approach in writing in tkinter, it's shorter and easier to reuse and structure the gui app.

Answer (score 1):

The line `x = number_input.get()` will return a string, but you are trying to use it as a number. Use the line `x = float(number_input.get())` instead. This would have been clear if you included the error printout:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'
```

Also, it would be much better to avoid global variables, but that's another issue for another day.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I tried it also. It gives this error. ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Yeah, if your input is empty or has non-numeric values, it's not going to be able to be converted into a float.

Comment: But I input numeric values still gives the same error